# How to creat a report of recurring donors

Tags: civireport

How do I get a report of all the donors who are set up for automatically give the same amount each month

Answer (score 6):

You can use Recurring Contributions(CiviCRM >> Reports >> Contribution Reports) report to see all the recurring contribution setup in the system.

You can also use [Extended report](https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports) extension where it gives more reports for recurring.

Comment: I like the "iATS Payments - Recurring Contributions" report that comes with the extension

Comment: There's also a report in this extension: https://github.com/adixon/ca.civicrm.contributionrecur that has some more bits than the built in one.